# Reactjs - Select box with varying first option based on passed attribute

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to show the first option different based on an attribute I pass.

In the search page, I want the user to be able to select "Any" option.

In the edit profile page, "Any" option should not be shown because that is only for search.

**Edit profile page**

```
<option value="0" disabled selected>
    Select Religion
</option>
```

**Search page**

```
<option value="Any" selected>
    Any Religion
</option>
```

Search profile page has this code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
..
import ReligionInput from '../edit-profile/religion-input'
..
..
<ReligionInput value={religion} change={this.changeReligion} any="Y" />
...
```

And ReligionInput has a check for any == Y or not but its not working and always has the Any option. What is wrong with the code below ?

```
import religionOptions from './religion-options'

const InputReligion = ({ value, change, any }) => (
  <div className="edit_religion_div">
    <Select
      placeholder="Select option"
      value={value}
      valueChange={e => change('religion', e)}
      className="edit_religion my2"
    >
    {any} == 'Y' ?
  `<option value="Any" selected>
    Any Religion
  </option>` :
  `<option value="0" disabled selected>
    Select Religion
  </option>`
      {religionOptions.map((e, key) => {
        return <option key={key} value={e.value}>{e.name}</option>;
       })}
    </Select>
  </div>
)

InputReligion.propTypes = {
  value: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  change: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
}
```

All other options come from religionOptions.

Answer (score 0):

A dirty way of doing it would be.

```
<option value={ any=='Y' ? '0' : 'Any' } selected>{ any=='Y' ? 'select' : 'any religion' }</option>
```

Yeah, not really a fan of those conditions either.
A cleaner and more readable approach would be:

```
const InputReligion = (props) => {
    let defaultOption = null;
  if (props.any == 'Y' ) {
    defaultOption = <option value='Any' selected>Any religion</option>
  } else {
    defaultOption = <option value='0' selected disabled>Select Religion</option>
  }

  return (
    <div className="edit_religion_div">
      <select placeholder="Select Option"
        className="edit_religion my2"
        value={ props.value }
        valueChange={ e => change('religion', e)}
        >
        { defaultOption }
        {
            religion.map( (e, key) => {
            return <option key={ key } value={ e.value }>{ e.name }</option>
          })
        }
      </select>
    </div>
  )
}
```